# stoping an animation 'scrollLeft' or 'scrollRight' when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to hack a plugin to work to my client's requirement.
Basically the plugin is a image gallery where it has thumbnails and a large preview. the thumbnails are inside the carousel. Now, I want to disable the auto scrolling when it is on top the image(s) or inside the container.

I (w/ big help of SO user) already did switched event to hover when viewing the the large preview.

You can see a demo here: http://jsbin.com/enezol/12

> ```
> thumbs.hover(
>   function(){
>     //Do not scroll or move when the mouse pointer is inside the list of thumbnails
>     $('.ad-thumb-list').stop();  
>   },
>
>   function(){
>     //Back to its orginal state
>     // ???
>   }
> ```

I'm trying to disable a function (autoscrolling) that when the mouse are inside the container containing of the thumbnails It shouldn't move. It's hard for user to view the thumbnails if it keeps moving from left to right.

You might be wondering why I switch the 'click' event to a 'hover' event, reason for that is client's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth a shot to try cancelling the event, like so...

```
$('#myElement').bind( 'mouseenter', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // just to be sure
});
```

Comment: I was wondering where do i get the event? and how will i know the event is occurring.. thanks!